# jmeter distributed test´s benefits,

Tags: jmeter, distributed

I've managed to make a simple test with JMeter and a maximum of 400 virtual threads before my laptop gets frozen. It has 8 gigabytes of RAM and a processor Intel core i5 with 2.4 GHz.

Then I´ve made two slave nodes by using Oracle Virtual Box, and a master node, all in my laptop. I´ve run the test in non-GUI mode and the maximum number of virtual threads I can run before my laptop gets frozen is also 400, by setting 200 as number of threads on the JMX file (200 for each slave makes 400 threads in all)

So if the maximum number of threads I can run is the same with a single machine and with two slaves and one master configuration Which is the sense of the node slave configuration? It has no advantages. What am I doing wrong? May it be due to the fact that the slave nodes are virtual instead of real ones?

By another side, the .jtl file I get for the 400 virtual threads weights 18 megabytes, and JMeter´s listeners can not read all its steps. The error message is

```
jmeter.save.CSVSaveService: Error parsing field 'bytes' at line 67515 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "text" "
```

So How can I see the complete results of a test with a big number of threads? Is it a problem of RAM lacking or a JMeter´s limitation?

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense in using master-slave configuration given you run everything on a single host. Given you can simulate 400 virtual users using one machine you should be able to simulate 400 more by adding one more machine (given it will have the same or similar specifications) so it should be like this:

- 1 machine - 400
- 2 machines - 800
- 3 machines - 1200
- etc.

But again, [distributed testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) goal is to scale JMeter when you have reached the limits of a single load generator machine and haven't delivered the required load. Running more than one JMeter Server (slave) on a single machine doesn't add any value.

---

Also make sure you're following recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for tuning JMeter engines for maximum performance, I would expect much more than 400 virtual users out of Core i5 with 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: Hello Dmitri. By following your advices  I´ve managed to increase the number of virtual users to 1200. Thank you so much.